# двумерный массив си при помощи malloca

Tags: c++, c, массивы

пытаюсь реализовать код который во время того как пользователь вводит символ программа выделяет динамический двумерный массив и добавляет туда этот символ. моя программа работает не на всех наборах слов. если ввести слишком длинную строку, программа делает пустой вывод. вот мой код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char** words=NULL; 
    char* tmp=NULL;
    char c=0; 
    int x=0,len=0,z=0;
    words = (char**)malloc(20*sizeof(char*)); 
    words[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c!=' '){
            tmp = (char*)realloc(words[x],sizeof(char));
            words[x]=tmp;
            words[x][len]=c;
            len++;
        }
        else{
            words[x][len] = '\0';
            x++;
            words[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
            len=0;
        }
    }
    words[x][len] = '\0';
    for (z=0;z<x+1;z++){
        printf("%s",words[z]);
    }
    free(words);
    words = NULL;
    free(tmp);
    tmp = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`realloc(words[x],sizeof(char))` — как был у вас выделен 1 (прописью: *один*) байт, так и остается один...

`realloc` не добавляет указанное количество памяти, а выделяет его.

И, кстати, вы не проверяете, что именно возвращают ваши функции выделения памяти.